# nested form issues rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I am using nested form in my rails app. I have user has_many user_skills association. Now in my form I have two sections 'user in skills' and 'user out skills' and add more option for both. I have added one field named 'skill_type' in my user_skill model to distinguish between 'in skills' and 'out skills' which is saving values 'in_skill' and 'out_skill' respectively.

But I am confused how do I handle it in rails.

I have added this in my form, but that's doesn't gonna help me.

```
.col-xs-12.no_pad.skils-fieldset            
   %legend In Skills
     = f.fields_for :user_skills do |user_skill|
       = render :partial => "users/user_skills", :locals => {:f => user_skil l}
     = link_to_add_fields "Add", f, :user_skills, true, "users/user_skills"


.col-xs-12.no_pad.skils-fieldset            
   %legend Out Skills
     = f.fields_for :user_skills do |user_skill|
       = render :partial => "users/user_skills", :locals => {:f => user_skil l}
     = link_to_add_fields "Add", f, :user_skills, true, "users/user_skills"
```

Obviuosly it would populate all the skills for that user in both the sections.

How do I handle this?

I tried adding conditions like this :

```
-if user_skill.skill_type == 'in_skill'
  = render :partial => "users/user_skills", :locals => {:f => user_skil l}
```

What is the better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user_skills.select {|skill| skill.skill_type == 'in_skill'}
```

above snippet will return only `in_skill` type of skills, subsequently you can iterate on it instead of using the bulky if condition

You can also put in_skills and out_skills in separate variables and iterate on those in your template